Magento 2.4.7 grid using ui_component set column sortOrder
I am creating a new grid in Magento 2.4.7 using ui_component and it won't respect columns sortOrder values.
This is column example:
<column name="created_at" sortOrder="999" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column">
    <settings>
        <filter>text</filter>
        <label translate="true">Created At</label>
        <sortable>true</sortable>
    </settings>
</column>

Recent Magento 2.4.* versions do not accept the use of <argument> anymore. As per documentation it should use sortOrder inside the column tag as I wrote but it simply won't work.
Thank you very much for your help.

you may go to magento project in check your current database fine tabel ui_bookmark in this table you can search sales_order_grid then row delete after applying static content deploy commands. please delete row backup your database.
sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/


then check your custom field sort order change.
if any question then tell me.

I hope your bug is solved so please accept my answer.
